# Wait for variable to be defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code in a Rails controller:

```
def show
  doc     = Document.find(params[:id])
  session = Crocodoc.get_session(doc.uuid)
  @url    = Crocodoc.session_based_viewer_url(session[:sessionId])
end
```

I need to wait until `session` is defined (or IOW wait for `Crocodoc.get_session` to return) before showing the view. How should this be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to rename the @url instance var to something else in order for it to get passed to the view.

Answer (score 1):

It's already handled. The view is rendered right after the controller action returns (unless you render it explicitly during the action). At that point `session` will be out of scope, but `@url` will be defined.

Comment: Thanks. But what I'm not getting is if I run this in console it is fine, but viewing in browser, `@url` and `session` are nil in the view. I thought what you said would be the case, but then I thought maybe since `Crocodoc.get_session` is an API request (read: going out to the net) it's not returning before the view is shown.

Comment: @Michael Irwin, it may be that `@url` is being _assigned_ `nil` during the action. Test the value of `@url` after its assignment, before leaving the action, with a `puts` or `debugger`. If the view is being rendered then `get_session` is returning _something_.